# jQuery Autocomplete - Palavras Chave

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Estou usando este plugin (https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) para fazer uma barra de pesquisa no sistema. Ela funciona perfeitamente. Mas eu gostaria de saber se tem como usar palavras de referência. Gostaria de pesquisar por palavras chaves, e ele me retornar elementos relacionados.
Exemplo: Pesquisar por "Barco" e ele mostrar elementos com a palavra "Naval".

Comment: Não é isso aqui que vc quer: [categories](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories)?

Comment: Votei por deixar aberta, pois foi possivel responder explicando o uso da `API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O parametro source suporta uma função (`function`), um exemplo simples:

```js
$(".sugestoes").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
      if (request.term === "barco") {
          response(["naval"]);
      }
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="sugestoes">
```

### Usando Ajax

Você pode combinar com Ajax para retornar os resultados de uma banco de dados ou qualquer outra coisa:

```
$(".sugestoes").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
      $.ajax("consulta.php", {
           "dataType": "json",
           "data": { "termo": request.term }
      }).done(function (resposta) {
           response(resposta);
      });
  }
});
```

A página pode ser em qualquer linguagem o que importa é que ela deve retornar neste formato:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

Para consultar no back-end se for PHP use `$_GET['termo']` (mas você pode alterar para o que desejar), exemplo:

```
<?php
switch ($_GET['termo'])
{
   case 'barco':
       echo '["naval", "remo", "bote"]';
   break;

   case 'foo':
       echo '["bar", "baz"]';
   break;
}
```