# Erro na requisição com jquery-autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte arquivo [**gulpfile.js**](https://gist.github.com/ivanferrer/2dfd05155a9f4d005c61536d3f9a6005) de compilação, para gerar os arquivos `css` e `js`. Ele está me gerando dois arquivos:

```
$('#instituicao').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.getJSON("/path/ajax", { q: request }, function(result) {
                response($.map(result, function(item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    return item.nome;                        
                }));
            });
        },
        minLength: 5,
        delay: 100
});
```

Quando digito, o objeto é impresso no console:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo do `JSON` do `Objeto` carregado:

> `[{"id":"7","nome":"EEEF EURIDICE LOPES PEDROSO","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"},{"id":"10","nome":"EEEFM JUSCELINO KUBITSCHEK DE OLIVEIRA","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"},{"id":"20","nome":"EEEF TANCREDO DE ALMEIDA NEVES","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"},{"id":"21","nome":"EEEFM PADRE EZEQUIEL RAMIN","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"}]`

Mas não na caixa de listagem do autocomplete da view.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="instituicao" name="instituicao" 
     class="form-control" placeholder="Nome da Instituição de ensino">
</div>
```

O que estou fazendo errado?

*PS:* Sei que não é `CSS`, pois quando envio o objeto desta maneira funciona:

> `var data = [{"id":"7","nome":"EEEF EURIDICE LOPES PEDROSO","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"},{"id":"10","nome":"EEEFM JUSCELINO KUBITSCHEK DE OLIVEIRA","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"},{"id":"20","nome":"EEEF TANCREDO DE ALMEIDA NEVES","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"},{"id":"21","nome":"EEEFM PADRE EZEQUIEL RAMIN","endereco":"aqui vir\u00e1 o endere\u00e7o"}];`

```
$('#instituicao').autocomplete({
      valueKey:'nome',
      source: [data],
      minLength: 5,
      delay: 100
});
```

Comment: Será que o problema é nesta parte `$.map(result, function(item) {
                    console.log(item);
                    return item.nome;

                })`? É jquery-ui né? Veja se isso ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/175148/3635

Comment: Que autocompletar é esse? Você viu na documentação qual o formato do objeto JSON que ele espera? pois acho bem pouco provável que ele aceite valores com a chave "nome"(português) ou uma lista de objetos contendo todos os atributos da entidade.

Comment: Estou usando esse: [jquery-autocomplete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-autocomplete)

Comment: @IvanFerrer acho que ao invés de `{ q: request }`, o correto seria `{ q: request.term }`, teste as duas possibilidades da resposta

Comment: Aqui tem mais sobre a [documentação](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/autocomplete) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi usando outra library, que funciona perfeitamente:

http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-remote

```
function highlightText(data, term) {

    term = term.replace(/(\s+)/,"(<[^>]+>)*$1(<[^>]+>)*");
    var pattern = new RegExp("("+term+")", "gi");
    data = data.replace(pattern, "<mark>$1</mark>");
    data = data.replace(/(<mark>[^<>]*)((<[^>]+>)+)([^<>]*<\/span>)/,"$1</mark>$2<mark>$4");

    return data;
}

function autoCompleteSchools(field) {

    var $el = $('#'+field);

    var options = {
        url: function(param) {
             return "path/ajax" +  param;
        },
        getValue: function(element) {
            return  element.nome;
        },
        template: {
            type: "custom",
            method: function(value, item) {
                var param = $el.val();
                return '<span class="school">'+highlightText(item.nome, param)+'</span><br><span class="address">'+highlightText(item.endereco, param)+'</span>';
            }
        },
        list: {
            onSelectItemEvent: function() {
                var value = $el.getSelectedItemData().label;
                var id = $el.getSelectedItemData().id
                $('#id_school').val(id).trigger("change");
                $el.val(value).trigger("change");
            },
            maxNumberOfElements: 10,
            theme: "square"
        },
        select:function(event, element){
            return element.label
        }
    };

    $el.easyAutocomplete(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que o problema é que você não está passando o parametro de maneira correta:

```
$.getJSON("/path/ajax", { q: request }, function(result) {
```

Acredito que o correto seria isto:

```
$.getJSON("/path/ajax", { q: request.term }, function(result) {
```

Outra possibilidade é que se passando diretamente com `[]`, então tenha que fazer no callback também:

```
$.getJSON("/path/ajax", { q: request }, function(result) {
    response([result]);
});
```

Comment: Não mudou nada fazendo isso.